# How to auto adjust Y axis plot lines in live high chart

Tags: highcharts

How to auto adjust plot lines in live plot
for example:Plot line i set to value:1.25 and random data are coming between 1-2.plot line will be visible.this works fine.suppose random data coming in the range 100-200,plot line will become hidden. i want to adjust plot lines irrespective of random data we generate.plot lines always visible.

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please.

Comment: Hi, I have created here http://jsfiddle.net/z6QXW/9/. At first plot line wont visible,in middle for some points plot line will be visible.at last plot line will hidden

Comment: And you want to always visible that plotLine? Just set max for yAxis to higher than 10000 and should work fine. Or just remove that plotLine and add new one in other place.

Comment: Here i have set max to 10000,Not working. http://jsfiddle.net/z6QXW/10/.i can't monitor data to remove and add plotlines.it should auto adjust plot lines based inputs.

Comment: I have seen no info on how you are defining what value the plotLine should have. If you are setting it to 1.25 what do you expect to happen when you have y values of 1 million? How is the value of the plotLine determined?

Comment: i set plot line max to 10000 and value to 1000.When the data are near to 1000,plot line will visible.for rest of the data plot line will be hidden.my requirement is plot line should be visible all the time in the plot irrespective of data. here i have created example http://jsfiddle.net/z6QXW/11/

Comment: I mean yAxis max, not plotLine (how would something like max for plotLine work?). PlotLine is not visible when values are relatively small which is correct. If you just want to draw a line on a part of a chart, use renderer.

Comment: I want plot line to be visible for small values without rendering.Is it possible in highchart?Because other charts like component one chart  have this feature.

Comment: As Pawel mentioned, you can use renderer to add static line http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path()

Answer (score 0):

set the max plot line value to any fixed number plots the plot line.

from then onwards the plot line will be visible. if the value of plot lines is very small compared to the scale then it may be tough. in this case go for a logarithmic scale. That will help.

```
yAxis:{
type: 'logarithmic'
}
```

updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/z6QXW/12/

hope this will help you